# Windows GUI file viewer that only displays printable characters

Tags: windows, gratis, gui, plain-text, ascii

Please recommend a gratis Windows GUI-based file viewer that only displays [printable characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).  These are approximately ASCII characters 32-126.

Basically, I want to be able open a binary file and quickly see the readable text inside.

- Search (find) functionality is a big plus, but not required.
- Portable apps are also big plus, but not required.
- Editing functionality is not required.